# how to add JDK documentation jar file (the file containing documentation for JDK classes like String etc) to JDeveloper?

Tags: java, jar, documentation, jdeveloper

my JDeveloper does not contain any documentation for JDK classes, all built-in classes and methods have no declaration I can't show what Specifically the methods do, I downloaded the documentation jar file but don't know how to add it in JDeveloper.

Answer (score 1):

Download src-jdk.zip file and place it in oracle_common/jdk folder.

In JDeveloper. Go to Java SE Definitions under Tools – Manage Libraries. Select 1.(version).* definition under User (not under Extension), and add src-jdk.zip to Source Path. JDK definition under Extension is Read Only, but when you restart JDeveloper after this change, Source Path will be updated for Extension JDK as well.

Restart JDeveloper. You will now see source for JDK java classes.

Comment: the JDK documentation jar file is not for specific project it's for any project. simply when you use any method in any built-in class if you want to show what specifically it performs, you go to the method declaration. the problem is that my JDeveloper does not contain that declaration. the JDK documentation jar file can be added to solve this problem and i wanna know how to add it. i tried the (libraries and class path) solution but it did not work